# Parsing WildFly logs by application name

Tags: java, logging, wildfly

I have several web applications deployed as `war` files on a Wildfly application server.

All logs of those web applications are written in console and to default `server.log` file.

Is there a way to determine which Application generate the single line of log?

It has to be managed through WildFly or in the application's code?

Answer (score 0):

You can create log file per deployment to determine which application is generating which logging. Or add %t to output the name of the thread that generated the logging event.

Comment: "Create log file per deployment" can be done by WildFly or should be done inside the application code (eg: log4j)?

Comment: You could also look at logging-profiles https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration#LoggingConfiguration-LoggingProfiles

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins i've done some test but i'm stuck here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43874428/wildfly-logging-profile-not-working-with-log4j