# WildFly Logging Profile not working with log4j

Tags: java, logging, jboss, wildfly-10

Following [*JBOSS Example Logging Profile Configuration* guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Administration_and_Configuration_Guide/Example_Logging_Profile_Configuration.html) I've created a logging profile on my WildFly10 server.

I've edited my `MANIFEST.MF` adding

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Logging-Profile: accounts-app-profile
```

But i can't find logs in `jboss.server.log.dir\ejb-trace.log` as expected.

This is my log4j.properties

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout


# ConsoleAppender.
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d - myApp: %m %n
```

This is my class:

```
public class myClass {

    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(myClass.class);

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getTest(){

        //logs a debug message
        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
            logger.debug("This is debug: ");
        }

        //logs an error message with parameter
        logger.error("This is error : ");


        String result = " this is a test";

        return result;
    }
}
```

Any hints?

Comment: If you're using a log4j configuration a logging profile won't work. You have to use one or the other.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins: Thanks I suspected that.. but because I haven't found any documentation about i've done this test... I accept it as an answer.

Comment: There's documentation here https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Logging+Configuration.